# Installing older builds with Apple's Testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

Does Apple's TestFlight App provide a mechanism to instal an older build?

A use scenario is as follows:

- **An actual release begins as TestFlight build**. You test it, then submit it for review to Apple.
- **While Apple are reviewing**, you're doing your job, developing new features and sending new builds to TestFlight so your colleagues can test them.
- **When Apple finish reviewing**, you want to do some final tests of the version you are about to deploy in to the wild – you can't instal this version though, because the TestFlight App only provides the latest build.

… Sure, you tagged the release version in your SCM. You can checkout, build, install and run that. But installing *the* binary you are about to deploy for pre-release testing (running against the live backend server that you've just patched) is what will give you that warm blanket of safety.

Thanks.

Comment: You can still use the old TestFlight system (testflightapp.com) to install any build.

Comment: Thanks @MarcusAdams, which the old test flight persists, that's a good work around.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to test older builds with TestFlight. You can just use the link provided in the email you received when you uploaded the older build for testing. You will see something like this.

> To test this app, open TestFlight on your iOS device using iOS 8.0 or later and install the update.

Tap on "TestFlight" in the above line. This will open TestFlight with a link to the older build. And you can install it if it hasn't yet expired.

Hope this helps!

**Update**

As of April 11, 2017, TestFlight now supports multiple builds. 
https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/

You can navigate to the Previous Builds section of the app in TestFlight and get access to builds which are up to 90 days old.

Answer (score -2):

you can just upload the binary you used to submit to the AppStore, upload a build to the testflightapp.com website and distribute to you and your team. The installed app will be identical to the one you are about to release - I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, that sounds promising – but will it work if the new build you upload has a version and build number behind that currently being actively tested?

Comment: I tested this and it doesn't work for the reason I speculated at in the previous comment. If you try (once you have uploaded other builds) you'll get an error "Redundant Binary Upload. There already exists a binary upload with the build version … ".